# Can I manage a mobile project(Android) and a web project(web client and server code) on the same GIT repository?

Tags: github, repository

Is there any Github new feature that let you manage all the parts of your project (both mobile and web, client and server) code on the same repository?. I have one android project and now I need to upload the code for my MEAN web app.......Should I just create 2 different repositories?....Is there a better way than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any Github new feature that let you manage all the parts of your project (both mobile and web, client and server) code on the same repository?

If you really want to do this you could put each project into a subdirectory:

- `project/`

  - `.git/`
  - `android/`
  - `web/`

But I wouldn't recommend it. You have two separate codebases, and each should live in its own repository. There is plenty of information floating around the web about why this is a better approach when working with Git.

If you have code to share between them you could use a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) for the common code, or pull it in with a dependency manager.

Comment: thanks my friend...I googled it but I couldn't find this...I already did as you suggest. The web app goes into one repo and the android app into another one....The ios app will go into a third one as well...It's not annoying at all, but I like to do things the right way from the beggining